How to extrude geometry node effect on a different axis
I'm working on this project where I have to animate a water along a path. I've been watching a tutorial for animating water along a path, it was good until a point. I would like to geometry node effect to extrude along the X axis instead of the Y in order to look like the flyer image I've provided.



Could you provide a broader picture of your GN graph and also your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

you could set the tilt of the curve to change the direction.
